# coins change dp solution - why the order of iterative loop matter

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

Why does the order of the iteration loop matter here?

```py
    def change1(self, amount, coins):
        """
        :type amount: int
        :type coins: List[int]
        :rtype: int
        """
        if amount == 0:
            return 1

        dp = [0 for _ in range(amount + 1)]
        dp[0] = 1

        # dp[i] to denote the number of ways to sum up to amount i.
        for j in range(len(coins)): # switch those 2 statements would be wrong answer why???
            for i in range(1, amount + 1):
                if i - coins[j] >= 0:
                    dp[i] += dp[i - coins[j]]

        return dp[amount]

    def change2(amount, coins): # wrong answer
        """
        :type amount: int
        :type coins: List[int]
        :rtype: int
        """
        if amount == 0:
            return 1

        dp = [0 for _ in range(amount + 1)]

        ## when amount is 0, # combinations is 1
        dp[0] = 1

        # dp[i] to denote the number of ways to sum up to amount i.
        for i in range(1, amount + 1):
            for j in range(len(coins)):  # switch those 2 statements would be wrong answer why???
                if i - coins[j] >= 0:
                    dp[i] += dp[i - coins[j]]

        return dp[amount]
```

## change 1

`dp[i-1] = dp[i-1-c2] + dp[i-1-c2] + dp[i-2-c2] + ..dp[0]`

`dp[i] = dp[i-c1] + dp[i-1-c1] + dp[i-2-c1] + ...dp[0]`
This is correct solution.

## change 2

`dp[i-1] = dp[i-1-c1] + dp[i-1-c2] + dp[i-1-c3] + dp[i-1-c4] + ... dp[0]`

`dp[i] = dp[i-c1] + dp[i-c2] + dp[i-c3] + dp[i-c4] + ... dp[0]`

Why this approach is WRONG?

Total amount `i` can be derived from a summation of choices from taking coin `c1` or `c2` or `c3`, this is more intuitive in my opinion.

I've checked a few references but couldn't find a satisfying answer.

EDIT: I also understand changing the order of nested loop will give wrong answer, I'm trying to understand why the 2nd approach has the wrong intuition while the 1st is correct.

[Coin Change: number of solutions when order matters vs. when order doesn't matter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44212730/coin-change-number-of-solutions-when-order-matters-vs-when-order-doesnt-matte)

[Coin change using dynamic programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32681464/coin-change-using-dynamic-programming)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously it must give wrong answer when you change the order of the nested loops.

The correct `dp` state of the problem is defined as follows:

```
dp[i][j] = # of ways to form amount j using first i coins
```

The optimal substructure here is that once you have solution for first `i` coins, you can extend it for `i+1` coins.

But when you flip the order of execution of loops, this substructure property does not hold.

In this case, you are first calculating the number of ways to form amount `i` using all the coins and extending it to find the number of ways to form amount `i+1`, for which the optimal substructure property does not hold true.

Comment: I didn't use `dp[i][j]` but `dp[amount]` denoting the number of ways to sum up to amount i. By definition, it should be `dp[amount] = dp[amount-c1] + dp[amount-c2] ...`

Comment: I used `dp[i][j]` for the sake of simplicity of explanation. If you look carefully then the `dp` state defined on `dp[n][amount]` is equivalent to `dp[amount]` where in each iteration instead of updating the original `dp` array, you have a new row for each iteration. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27880842/space-optimized-solution-for-coin-change

Comment: Yes, that explanation makes sense if you are optimizing from dp[i][j], however, what's wrong with`dp[amount]`denotation above - number of ways summing to amount using any of the coins

Comment: Both are same! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27880842/space-optimized-solution-for-coin-change

Comment: Thanks, basically denotation on dp[amount] in my case is wrong, dp[amount] is really the number of ways to sum up to amount i, `using the first j coins`.